# PromSQL list database same host label

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I need to create a graph on metric "oracledb_database_cpu_usages" with database label variable and obtain same host label.

METRIC:

```
oracledb_database_cpu_usages{database="DB1", host="host01", instance="127.0.0.1:9161", job="oracle"}
oracledb_database_cpu_usages{database="DB2", host="host01", instance="127.0.0.1:9161", job="oracle"}
oracledb_database_cpu_usages{database="DB3", host="host02", instance="127.0.0.1:9161", job="oracle"}
oracledb_database_cpu_usages{database="DB4", host="host02", instance="127.0.0.1:9161", job="oracle"}
oracledb_database_cpu_usages{database="DB5", host="host01", instance="127.0.0.1:9161", job="oracle"}
```

If my variable is database=DB1 the output should be:

```
oracledb_database_cpu_usages{database="DB1", host="host01", instance="127.0.0.1:9161", job="oracle"}
oracledb_database_cpu_usages{database="DB2", host="host01", instance="127.0.0.1:9161", job="oracle"}
oracledb_database_cpu_usages{database="DB5", host="host01", instance="127.0.0.1:9161", job="oracle"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved. I created a variable "Host" in grafana with variable in "Database_Name".

[grafana variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6ZEx.png)

"Database_Name" is the variable selection in dashboard Time series graph.

[time series query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKYJV.png)

Now work as i expected